# /etc/cron.d/cronjob

Tags: cron

I am trying to get a cronjob in /etc/cron.d/ to run the first Saturday of every month.

Here is what I have so far:

```
0 1 1-7 * 6 [`date +\%d` == 06] root && /home/test/cron-test.sh
```

I change the system date Jan 14, 2017 (a Saturday in 2017) at midnight and checking `tail /var/log/syslog | grep cron-test` reports:

```
Jan 14 00:59:21 Inspiron-1545 cron[936]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/cron.d/cron-check1
Jan 14 00:59:21 Inspiron-1545 cron[936]: (*system*cron-check1) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System-wide crontabs have the five date and time fields on each line, then the username to run the cronjob as, then the command line. In yours, the time fields seem ok, but the sixth field `` [`date `` is rather odd for a username. The error message hints at that.

Since you have `root` mentioned after the snippet in brackets, I think you may have just misplaced the username, so you should have:

```
0 1 1-7 * 6 root [`date +\%d` == 06] && /home/test/cron-test.sh
```

This still has the issue that `[` is a command just like others, so you have to use whitespace after the `[` and before the `]`. And `==` isn't standard for comparison, `=` is. Also, for command substitution, `$(cmd)` is just nicer than backticks, so let's try:

```
0 1 1-7 * 6 root [ $(date +\%d) = 06 ] && /home/test/cron-test.sh
```

But `date +%d` tells the day of month, and now you're only running on the sixth day of the month (regardless of weekday). The third and fifth fields (day of month and day of week) work a a bit oddly together: the cronjob runs if **either** of them matches. But we want to run only on a Saturday, and only on the first to seventh days of month, so we have to check one of the conditions manually.

```
0 1 1-7 * * root [ $(date +\%u) -eq 6 ] && /home/test/cron-test.sh
```

The cronjob itself runs on all of the first seven days of the month, but the manual test `[ $(date +%u) -eq 6 ]` checks that the day of week is Saturday, before actually running the main command.

(Some versions of the `crontab(5)` manual page have an example almost like that, but I can't find an online version of it.)

Comment: Logic says you don't need the date test with just `0 1 1-7 * 6 root /home/test/cron-test.sh`. 01:00am, the first 7 days of a month, and on Saturday only. That's only going to execute once each month. There is only going to be one Saturday at some point in the first 7 days of any month.

Comment: @Deathgrip, logic yes, crontab no. The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) explicitly states that if both are restricted, the command runs if _either_ field matches: ""30 4 1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday."

Comment: @ilkkachu - Thanks for your detailed and excellent solution!!!  It works perfectly!!!!

Comment: @Deathgrip - Thanks for your post also.  BTW - I did try the solution you recommended, the problem I ran into is that it ran every Saturday of the month.